# Facebook pages plugin not showing on website

Tags: facebook

I am currently writing a website for a local charity run preschool and they would like their Facebook feed on the site.
For this I have used the Facebook Pages plugin. Unfortunately, following their instructions, I don't get anything on the website.

I'm not getting any errors in the console, and the Facebook URL is valid.
I understand to view this specific page the user needs to be logged in to Facebook, which I am, and I'm also able to view the page in the same browser with no problems.

The code I have is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=261857213845517";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and the HTML is:

```
  < div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/thevillageplaygroup/" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">< /div>
```

(note, I've added spaces in the div opening and closing tags as I couldn't get it to show up otherwise, sorry).

I've tried changing the Facebook URL to https://www.facebook.com/facebook as in the examples and that works so I'm presuming it's something to do with the page itself but I can't find any privacy or security settings which seem relevant.

**EDIT**
The page has security restrictions in place which mean the user needs to be logged in to Facebook and in the UK.
My account is able to access it ok through Facebook, just not using the plugin on the website

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The page does not seem to be public yet, or it has other access restrictions - I only get “Sorry, this content isn't available right now”

Comment: Hi, thanks for checking. The page is run by the charity so I need to run any privacy changes by them.
That said, it should be showing if you are logged in to Facebook and in the UK, is that not the case?
(I'll edit the original question with these restrictions)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin#privacy: _“Facebook Pages with privacy restrictions cannot be embedded.”_

Comment: Aah, I missed that :( I'll let the charity know and see what they want to do next.
Thanks for pointing that out, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by CBroe, it looks to be an issue with using the page feed for a page with privacy restrictions

“Facebook Pages with privacy restrictions cannot be embedded.”

I, wrongly, assumed that seeing as was logged into Facebook and could access the page that I would be able to see the feed. It seems Facebook disallow use of the plugin for pages with privacy restrictions regardless.